# Finding $A$ from $x$ and $b$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For $Ax = b$, if we are given:

$$ x= \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
4
\end{bmatrix}$$

is the unique solution where:

$$ b = \begin{bmatrix}
4 \\
2 \\
12 \\
8
\end{bmatrix}$$

How could we find the dimension of the column space of $A$ and the reduced row echelon form of $A$?

I can figure out how to get the dimensions of the matrix and the final column:

$$ A= \begin{bmatrix}
x_{11} & x_{12} & 1  \\
x_{21} & x_{22} & 1/2  \\
x_{31} & x_{32} & 3 \\
x_{41} & x_{42} & 2
\end{bmatrix}$$

But not sure how to find the other parts, unless we make assumptions on the first two columns of $A$.

Comment: There is a general theorem saying that the dimension of the solution space of a linear system is the number of columns minus the rank of $A$. I don't know what you mean by "ref form".

Comment: Hey, yeah I'm just not sure how we can make any assumptions on the first two columns, they could be anything imo, therefore both Linearly Independent and Dependent columns could be in columns 1 and 2. 

And sorry it was meant to be rref (reduced row echelon form) updated that now.

Comment: From my first comment, it follows that the columns must be linearly independent...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine the rest you need to use the fact that the solution is unique. Since the system has exactly one solution, the rank of $A$ (i.e. the dimension of the column space of $A$) must be equal to the number of variables (i.e. the number of columns). Thus the column space has dimension 3. The reduced row echelon form will then be
$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0\end{array}\right].$$

You could also approach it without the general theorem that I used above. Note that the last column cannot belong to the span of the first two, because otherwise you could produce another solution in the following way: if $\textbf{v}_1,\textbf{v}_2,\textbf{v}_3$ are the column vectors, and $a_1\textbf{v}_1 + a_2\textbf{v}_2 = v_3$, then $x = [2/a_1\ 2/a_2\ 0]^T$ would also be a solution. Furthermore, $\textbf{v}_1$ and $\textbf{v}_2$ need to be linearly independent, because if $\textbf{v}_1 = \alpha\textbf{v}_2$, then any $x = [a\ -\alpha a\ 4]^T$ would be a solution. Together it means that the column vectors need to be linearly independent.